# Wiremock and XPath attribute testing

Tags: java, xml, xpath, wiremock

Assume I have an XML request containing the following snippet

```xml
<foo bar="12356"/>
```

My service sends this snippet to another services to do things. That service expects a `foo` node with `bar` attribute and no text node. The following expression matches that node just fine

```xml
//foo[@bar='12356']
```

The problem is that Wiremock expects a text node to be present in matched `foo` nodes, as a result, it considers the previous expression to NOT match.

Using wiremock how do you test XML for matching attributes instead of text nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to XPath spec, namespaces matter. If the xml file was the following

```xml
<?xml ...>
<Envelope>
    <foo bar="12356"/>
</Envelope>
```

Then the XPath expression provided in question would work. But once you add `xmlns=` declaration, your node is no longer `foo` but rather `"[xmlns]":foo`. As a result, `//foo` only matches unprefixed `foo` elements.